# Delete Blank option Jquery and PHP

Tags: php

I need to remove the blank option.

This is a restaurant web page and this is the reservation form.
The thing is that they are reciving a lot of "blank" reservation hours because people don't specify the reservation hour.

Sorry for my English, I'm from Spain :)

[image]

The code:

HTML read by browser

```
    <div id="lashoras">
                                <select name="Hora" size="1" onChange="updateHoraPersonas();">
    <option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="1330">13:30</option>
    <option value="1400">14:00</option>
    <option value="1430">14:30</option>
    <option value="1500">15:00</option>
    <option value="1930">19:30</option>
    <option value="2000">20:00</option>
    <option value="2030">20:30</option>
    <option value="2100">21:00</option>
    <option value="2130">21:30</option><option value="2200">22:00</option></select>                     
                                </div>
```

source code HTML

```
<div id="lashoras">
                        <?php
                         echo $selectFullDay;
                        ?>
```

SelectFullDay PHP Var

```
$selectFullDay = build_select_options ("Hora","id_lookup","lookup","lookups",0," ",$onChange,$theWhere,$multiple,$orderby);
```

updateHoraPersonas Function

```
function updateHoraPersonas(){
    var mediodiaMax = maxPersonas;
    var nocheMax = maxPersonas;

    mediodiaMax = maxPersonas-curDia_mediodia_reservados;
    if(mediodiaMax<0) mediodiaMax = 0;

    nocheMax = maxPersonas-curDia_noche_reservados;
    if(nocheMax<0) nocheMax = 0;

    var hora = $('#lashoras').val();
    //hora blank for first, otherwise 1330

    //primero ver si llegado a tope de mediodia/noche
    if (hora <= horaCambio) {
        selectMax = mediodiaMax;
    } else {
        selectMax = nocheMax;
    }

    //y ahora hora a hora
    selectMax = Math.min(selectMax,horasArray[hora]);

    var Numero_de_personasSelect = "";
    for (i=1 ; i<= selectMax ; i++) {
        if (i==1) {
            selected = "selected='selected'";
        } else {
            selected = "";
        }


        Numero_de_personasSelect += "<option value='"+i+"' "+selected+" >"+i+"</option>";
    }

    if (selectMax <=0 ) {
        Numero_de_personasSelect += "<option value=''>Completo</option>";
    }

    $("#Numero_de_personas").html(Numero_de_personasSelect);


    //alert('mediodiaMax: '+mediodiaMax+' | nocheMax: '+nocheMax+' | selectMax: '+selectMax);}

</script>
```

....

Comment: Why dont you remove `<option value="" selected="selected"> </option>`, if selecting hours is mandatory

Comment: You are looking at this problem all wrong. They wouldn't get empty values if you did proper server side validation. Removing the empty option will create a whole new problem where the default value will be the value of the first option and you will end up with lots of reservations for that time when user forgets to select

Comment: Looking at the code you posted, I see nothing that adds options into the select for times.  The function `updateHoraPersonas` does not do that.  The problem here is in `build_select_options`, which we cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

Change the form submission so that the user cannot submit if the reservation time is not specified! This way you processing time does not increase on explicitly removing blank options

an exapmle

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['time'])){
  //'Enter valid details
}else{
  //redirect here
}
```

Comment: Indeed, do not give them the possibility to enter an empty value + validate your inputs!